# How to use SetTranslation() to fix a view at it's position?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

I used [CommonsWare's ViewPager](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1) (With the same code) to make a ViewPager with 6 pages that shows the previous and the next page along the current one.

So here is how it looks: (first image)  as you can see when I swipe the pager the first and the 4th page slide out/in from screen. (2nd image)

[image]

And here is what I want : ( I just want to fix the 1st and the 4th page's positions so the 2nd page goes on the first page)

*(The position of first page is -1 and the 4th is 1 )*

[image]

I just have problem with using `SetTranslationX(float value)` for "position >= 1" and "position <= -1"

What should I put in `SetTranslationX(float value)` to make fixed views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do it this way :

By looking at [JazzyViewPager's](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) code, I used `PositionOffsetpixels` for `setTranslationX()`  so here is how the code is look like :

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            OFFSET = positionOffsetPixels;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

and in pagetransformer I did like this :

```
if (position <= -1) {
view.setTranslationX(OFFSET);
}else if (position >=1) {
float mTrans = -view.getWidth()-pager.getPageMargin()+OFFSET;
view.setTranslationX(mTrans);
```

It worked like a charm ...